# Python Multiprocessing: Ending an infinite counter

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm new to multiprocessing, and I'm just trying to write a simple program in Python 3.2 which has a counter increasing indefinitely in one thread, while a second thread checks to see if a given value has been reached in the first thread. Once the value is reached, I would like the multiprocessing thread to close, and for the program to display a "Process Complete" statement.

As far as I understand it, the program would look something like (where the given value is 10):

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def Counter():
    i=1
    while i > 0:
        print("i: ",i)
        i+=1


def ValueTester(i):
    if i >= 10:
        *End Counter Function Thread*


if __name__ == '__main__':

    *Begin multiprocessing, one thread for "Counter" and a second for "ValueTester"*

    print("Process Complete")
```

I apologise for the vagueness of the psuedocode; I have read the Python documentation alongside several different examples, and I can't seem to find a simple solution.

Additionally, once this is working, how would I go about setting the given stopping value (i.e. passing a variable to `ValueTester`, rather than just using `10`)?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to be careful to make a clear distinction here between threads and processes.

Threads all operate under the same process. Values *accessed* can be shared
between threads. Values can be *changed* by threads in a safe (coordinated)
manner only if the value is protected by a `threading.Lock` before it is
changed. In CPython, the most common implementation of Python and also PyPy, but
in contrast to other implementations like Jython or Iron Python, the GIL (global
interpreter lock) prevents more than one thread from running at any given
time. So under CPython multiple threads actually run serially, not
concurrently. Still, multiple threads can be useful for I/O intentive work, such
as querying many websites, since there the majority of the time is spent waiting
for network (I/O) activity. The multiple threads therefore do not have to wait
as much, fighting for the access to a single CPU, as compared with tasks that
are CPU-intensive like mathematical computation.

Now having said all that, you are dealing with multiple *processes*, not
threads. Processes are independent of each other. They can and do run
concurrently on multiple CPUs if available (including under CPython). When you
spawn a process, the global values are copied from the originating process to
the spawned process. On some OSes, like Linux, that have "copy-on-write", the
values are actually shared between processes *until* a process tries to
overwrite a value, at which time the value is copied to become independent from
the other process. So when you modify values, *the two process end up with two
variables named the same but can have entirely different values*.

There are special objects provided by the multiprocessing module to facilitate
[sharing state between processes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes). These include `mp.Value`, `mp.Array`,
`mp.Manager`. Note that when you use these objects [you must also use a `mp.Lock`](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing)
to prevent one process from changing the value while another process is trying to do the same
thing. However, the Lock also slows down the processes, because one has to wait
for the lock to be released.

Now to signal a process when a condition has been reached in another process, use an `mp.Event`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def Counter(i, event, lock):
    with lock:
        i.value = 1
    while i.value > 0 and not event.is_set():
        print("i: ", i.value)
        with lock:
            i.value += 1


def ValueTester(i, stopval, event):
    while True:
        if i.value >= stopval:
            event.set()
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = mp.Value('d', 0.0)
    # A lock is not absolutely necessary here since only one process modifies
    # num, but I'm including it since it is necessary (to avoid race conditions)
    # in the more usual case when multiple processes may modify num.
    lock = mp.Lock()
    event = mp.Event()
    counter = mp.Process(target=Counter, args=(num, event, lock))
    counter.start()
    tester = mp.Process(target=ValueTester, args=(num, 10, event))
    tester.start()
    tester.join()
    counter.join()
    print("Process Complete")
```

For more examples on how to use multiprocessing, see [Doug Hellman's Python Module of the Week tutorial](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I'm afraid to say your code doesn't seem to quite work for me; it runs, but the counter is never stopped, and continues to run indefinitely. I wish I could suggest an improvement/alteration, but this is very new to me!

Comment: If your machine is very quick, then `ValueTester` may run *before* `i.value` is greater than `stopval`. In that case, the `ValueTester` function ends without setting the event. Then `Counter` may continue indefinitely. I'll modify the code to prevent this...

Comment: That appears to be working now, thank you! I wasn't aware that the counter will stop at various places depending on the speed of your computer.

Answer (score 1):

So what you need is some mechanism for the two threads (processes) to communicate with each other. Luckily, Python's multiprocessing module gives you a few options, one of which is a queue.

So the first thing to do is start these two def's, and pass in a shared queue that they can use to communicate. Since you want the main process to kill the child process, the first proc should start the second.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Queue

def counter(): #use lowercase c, 'Counter' is importable
    threshold = 10
    output = Queue(1) #for placing numbers on the queue
    input = Queue(1) #for looking for the signal that child is done
    child = Process(target=valuetester, args=(threshold, output, input))
    child.start()
    i=1
    while i > 0:
        output.put(i)
        print("i: ",i)
        i+=1 
        try:
            done = input.get_nowait()
            if done == 'Im Done!':
                print 'Process Complete!'
                child.join() #clean up the child proc
                return
        except Empty:
            pass #input is empty, no big deal


def valuetester(threshold, input, output):
    thresholdNotPassed = False
    while thresholdNotPassed:
        i = input.get()
        if i >= threshold:
            output.put('Im Done!')
            return 
        else:
            pass #nothing to do... just wait

#Start the counter proc. You could use the main process since its easier
if __name__ == 'main':
    counter()
```

A few things to note:
I made the queues have a maxsize of one... what this will do is block (hold at that line) if the queue is full.

You can see that I also used a get_nowait() for the main process to check if the child finished, otherwise using a normal `get` would block there and we would deadlock!

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the help! I am trying this out now; I got an error on `child = Process(...)` because I think it supposed to be `child = mp.Process(...)`. However, I had a similar issue with `except Empty:`; what module would I find `Empty` in?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I usually structure my imports as `from multiprocessing import ...`
Empty should be in `from Queue import Empty`